# LTI conne tion between moodle and brightspace

Tags: canvas, connection, moodle, moodle-api, lti

I am beginner in LTI so help me to create lti connection between moodle and brightspace

create lti connection between moodle and brightspace step by step

how can I create external tool in brightspace..??
and what is the consumer key and secret key here

Comment: To create an LTI connection btwn Moodle and Brightspace, you'll need to manually register the LTI tool in Moodle with the details from Brightspace. Then, in Moodle, you'll add an activity or resource using the External Tool option, configuring it with the specific LTI launch URL from Brightspace.The consumer key and secret are unique credentials used to secure the LTI connection. In Brightspace, these would be provided when you set up the LTI tool.Use credentials in Moodle when setting up the External Tool. they act as a username and password to establish a secure connection btwn the 2 systems

Comment: thank you so much  I have successfully established my connection. But getting issue with user synchronization. Brightspace users are not enrolled automatically in Moodle. what is the steps and settings in bright space to successfully work and

Comment: 1. Ensure that your LTI tool in Brightspace(BS) is correctly configured to pass user information to Moodle (make sure settings, roles, and permissions are set as needed) 2. make sure that BS is setup to share user data with moodle. 3 In BS, i belive should be a setting or a feature which enables it for automatic enrollment of users into linked moodle courses. 4 make sure permissions in BS allow LTI tool to modify enrollments in moodle 5. test synchronization. 6 check Moodle and BS docs for any guides about synchronization via LTI. 7. as a last resort you can try contacting moodle or BS (forum)

Comment: and I think the questions is about connection, not about "creation of external tool" so i would create another question for that one. As it would be easier for people to start helping and this post won't have 2 separate question in one as well. you can send or mention that new questions about external tool as well. and how are you looking at it right now? have you managed to progress in that direction?

Comment: "how can I create external tool in brightspace?" 1. Login as admin to BS. 2 Admin tools/settings or manage => "External Learning Tools", "LTI Advantage", or similar. 3. there might be a button "New Tool" or something like this. 4 provide some details to it. 5 use documention for both tools you are using/integrating into 6. save it and test it